# Ubuntu Phone : Change the device name

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to change the default device name ("bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition") of my Ubuntu Phone .

How can I proceed?

Comment: In which place do you want to change it? I'm not aware of a way in the UI to do this.

Answer (score 2):

## Bluetooth

At least for Bluetooth you can do the following:

1. Use adb

To use adb you must have developer mode enabled and [adb installed](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) (the sdk is enough, you don't need the entire IDE, which is Android specific anyway). If you have it installed you can follow these commands

```
$ adb shell
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ sudo vi /etc/machine-info
[sudo] password for phablet: {fill in your passphrase/PIN}
```

Now you can enter the name you want after `PRETTY_HOSTNAME`

```
PRETTY_HOSTNAME="Your preferred name here"
```

In stead of `vi` you can also use `nano` (i.e.:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ sudo nano /etc/machine-info
```

)

There is lots of help available on how to use `vi` or `nano`

2. Use a terminal app

In the *Ubuntu Store* there is an app called `Terminal`. When installed, you can use it to type the same commands as for adb.

Setting up adb is far more work, but I had it installed already and I prefer using a real keyboard over an on-screen keyboard for these kind of things.

## Device Hostname

You can also change the device hostname, but it is doesn't work as well as changing the `PRETTY_HOSTNAME` setting.

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~% sudo hostname <new-hostname>
```

Note that the actual hostname must be a [valid hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names)

A (big) caveat with this is, that – apparently – `/etc/` is not writeable by default, meaning that `hostname` will not update `/etc/hosts` since that file is not writeable. To be able to resolve its own hostname, the system needs `/etc/hosts` to contains a reference to its own hostname, otherwise you'll get error messages like "unable to resolve host ", since `/etc/hosts` only contains references to `ubuntu-phablet`.